# Typescript: re-using properties from an interface in a class

Tags: typescript

I'm experimenting with using a simple pattern for creating a type of 'value' object. To instantiate it, all properties should be specified in the constructor.

To avoid repeating the list of properties, I tried something like this:

```
interface Video {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

class VideoCl implements Video {

    constructor(properties: Video) {
        for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(properties)) {
            this[k] = v;
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, Typescript will not allow this as it requires all the properties from the interface to exist on the class as well.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this that removes the need for repeating the properties?

Comment: Declaration merging - make an interface of the same name as your class & extend the Video interface in it.

Comment: @Gerrit0 interfaces can have the same name as a class? This blows my mind. Would have made a few things I've been working on much simpler

Comment: @Gerrit0 wanna submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) with an interface of the same name.
Keep in mind that by doing this you are effectively lying to TypeScript. Even if a property declared in the interface is missing, TypeScript won't care.

```
interface VideoCl extends Video { }

class VideoCl {
    constructor(properties: Video) {
        for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(properties)) {
            this[k] = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Related to this, iterating over properties with `Object.entries`, `Object.keys`, or directly setting values with `Object.assign` on a class is dangerous. TypeScript won't protect you from the following code.

```
const properties = { id: 1, title: '', func: null };
const cls = new VideoCl(properties);
cls.func(); // Runtime error
```